# Listing all secret version Alias in gcp secret-manager through .net

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager, gcp-secret-manager

Like the title says, I've been trying to access all the secret version alias in a gcp secret but to no success. When trying to get `VersionAliases` from a `Secret` I always only get one version and nothing more even tho I know I added several more and I can see them in gcp console.
Bellow it's my code that I expected to work:

```
var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
foreach (var versionKey in secret.VersionAliases.Select(version => version.Key))
{
    versionAlias = versionKey;
    value = await ReadAsync(client, secretsEnumerator.Current.SecretName, versionKey);

    if (value != null)
        result.Add(versionAlias, value);
}
```

My ultimate goal is to be able to access certain secrets through an Id that is not the classic int that is used as a version Id in the secret-manager. This Alias system seems to me it's the way to go but different approaches are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can get one version, I assume that the service account used by your application has the necessary permissions to list and access the secret versions. The issue might be with the '`GetSecretAsync`' method, which may only retrieve the latest version by default.

You can retrieve all the version aliases for a GCP secret and access their values by using the '`ListSecretVersionsAsync`' method.

Here's an example:

```
var secretVersions = await client.ListSecretVersionsAsync(new ListSecretVersionsRequest
{
    Parent = secretName
});

foreach (var version in secretVersions)
{
    var versionAlias = version.Alias;
    var value = await ReadAsync(client, secretName, versionAlias);

    if (value != null)
    {
        result.Add(versionAlias, value);
    }
}
```